# What are the best R packages for a classification problem with use of Neural networks

Tags: r, neural-networks, svm, perceptron, rbf-network

Surfing on the internet shows me that there are a lot of different packages and functions which can be used to train neural networks via R. 
packages such as 'RSNNS', 'nnet','neuralnet', etc.

I'm trying to solve a classification problem and want to try different neural network techniques like, MLP, RBF and SVM.

Does anyone knows which packages or functions best can be used to classify the data.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you read the documentation for those packages, you'd see that they do not offer SVM implementations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package `caret` provides a really nice interface (and much more) to a number of neural network techniques in various packages, so you can easily switch between the different packages and functions. There is a comprehensive list [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/Neural_Network.html) of the different available methods related to neural networks. For example:

```
library(caret)

mod1 <- train(Species ~ ., 
        data = iris, 
        method = "nnet", 
        trControl = trainControl(method = "CV", number = 10))

mod2 <- train(Species ~ ., 
        data = iris, 
        method = "rbf", 
        trControl = trainControl(method = "CV", number = 10))
```

Allows using the `nnet` package and the `RSNNS` package by only changing `method`. For a nice tutorial on how the `caret` package works see [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html).

Furthermore, if you decide you can't choose which model you like best, [caretEnsemble](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caretEnsemble/vignettes/caretEnsemble-intro.html) is a new package which easily allows you to ensemble mutiple models.